# I'm trying to make a while loop that approximates the value of cos(x) so that its to within - or + 1-e10

Tags: r, while-loop, approximation

We must use a while loop to solve this problem (approximating the value of cos to within - or + 1-e10  ) and I believe I have all the right setup but I keep getting the error "missing value where  TRUE/FALSE needed"

The question stating

A Taylor expansion of a function is an expression of the function as an infinite sum of terms. We can approximate the function by taking the first several terms of the infinite sum. The more terms we include, the better will be our approximation.

The Taylor expansion of the cosine function $cos(x)$ is:
1-((x^2)/(2!))+(x^4)/(4!)...

```
x = pi/2
n = 0
approximation = 1
limit = 1e-10
while(approximation < (limit*(-1)) || approximation > limit){
  (term = c(((-1)^n)*((x)^(2*n)))/factorial(2*n))
  (n  = n + 1)
  (approximation = approximation + term)
}
approximation
```

This is the code that I attempted but like I said it keeps giving me the error stated above.

Comment: Suggestion: put a `cat()` or `print()` statement inside your while loop so you can see what's happening. (e.g. `cat(n, term, approximation, "\n")`)

Comment: I've found the problem: when `n` reaches `786`, your `term`'s numerator `((-1)^n)*((x)^(2*n))` maxes out at `Inf`inity.  Now your denominator `factorial(2*n)` has been `Inf` for some time, ever since `n` reached `86`; so until now, the overall quotient has been `0`: a finite number divided by `Inf`inity.  But when `n` reaches `786`, your `term` becomes `Inf / Inf`, which is `NaN`, and `approximation` is incremented to `approximation + NaN` which is still `NaN`.  With an `approximation` of `NaN`, your `while` conditions evaluate to `NA`, and `while(NA){...}` yields the error you encountered.

Comment: @Greg it shouldn't get that high though because of my conditions though right? Or is something wrong with my conditions in that the loop keeps going and doesn't restrict the loop until it just reaches an undefined value?

Comment: @Greg, I only glanced at the code, but presumably there is something wrong with the loop condition - it shouldn't take 86 iterations to reach this level of precision ... being **extremely** lazy, `eval(parse(text = taylor("cos(x)", var = "x", order = 30)$f), list(x = pi/2))` is 1e-16 ...

Comment: I don't think you can start `approximation` from 1 and expect the results to make sense?

Comment: @BenBolker If the code starts with `n <- 1` it will get a result making sense. I will post an answer.

Comment: @user23327933 _"Or is something wrong with my conditions in that the loop keeps going...?"_  I think the issue lies with how `n = 0` and `approximation = 1` are initialized: after the first iteration, approximation is `2` rather than `1`, which does _not_ match the Taylor series.  You should initialize `n = 1` instead, so you essentially complete the first term of the series before the loop even starts.

Comment: @Greg thanks again for the explaination, really helped me to understand what went wrong, appreciate it.

Comment: @user23327933 Happy to help!  If you're looking to go beyond debugging, I'd recommend the [`taylor_cos()` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77916170) by [@RuiBarradas](https://stackoverflow.com/u/8245406), for streamlining your code and improving both accuracy and performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

To avoid this error, simply initialize `n <- 1`, which aligns your terms with the Taylor series.

## Diagnosis

When you initialize `n <- 0`, the series starts with `2` rather than `1`, unlike the Taylor series.  This causes `approximation` to converge *wrongly* on `1`, by the 11th iteration.

```r
x = pi/2
n = 0
approximation = 1
limit = 1e-10
while(approximation < (limit*(-1)) || approximation > limit){
  (term = c(((-1)^n)*((x)^(2*n)))/factorial(2*n))
  (n  = n + 1)
  (approximation = approximation + term)
  
  # Debugging.
  cat(sep = "\n",
    sprintf("n = %3s; term = %22s; approximation = %17s", n, term, approximation)
  )
}
approximation
```

As discussed below, this loops out of control until throwing an error.

> ```
> n =   1; term =                      1; approximation =                     2
> n =   2; term =      -1.23370055013617; approximation =      0.76629944986383
> n =   3; term =      0.253669507901048; approximation =      1.01996895776488
> n =   4; term =     -0.020863480763353; approximation =     0.999105477001525
> n =   5; term =   0.000919260274839426; approximation =      1.00002473727636
> n =   6; term =  -2.52020423730606e-05; approximation =     0.999999535233992
> n =   7; term =   4.71087477881817e-07; approximation =      1.00000000632147
> n =   8; term =  -6.38660308379185e-09; approximation =     0.999999999934866
> n =   9; term =   6.56596311497947e-11; approximation =      1.00000000000053
> n =  10; term =  -5.29440020073462e-13; approximation =     0.999999999999996
> n =  11; term =    3.4377391790986e-15; approximation =                     1
> n =  12; term =  -1.83599165215524e-17; approximation =                     1
>
> # ...
>
> n =  85; term =  3.51311990046563e-270; approximation =                     1
> n =  86; term = -3.01715137758328e-274; approximation =                     1
> n =  87; term =                      0; approximation =                     1
> n =  88; term =                      0; approximation =                     1
>
> # ...
>
> n = 785; term =                      0; approximation =                     1
> n = 786; term =                      0; approximation =                     1
> n = 787; term =                    NaN; approximation =                   NaN
> Error in while (approximation < (limit * (-1)) || approximation > limit) { : 
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> ```

**But with `n <- 1` we *properly* obtain an `approximation` of `-6.51335680512735e-11`, which *terminates* on the 7th iteration:**

> ```
> n =   2; term =      -1.23370055013617; approximation =     -0.23370055013617
> n =   3; term =      0.253669507901048; approximation =    0.0199689577648782
> n =   4; term =     -0.020863480763353; approximation = -0.000894522998474732
> n =   5; term =   0.000919260274839426; approximation =  2.47372763646945e-05
> n =   6; term =  -2.52020423730606e-05; approximation = -4.64766008366076e-07
> n =   7; term =   4.71087477881817e-07; approximation =  6.32146951574058e-09
> n =   8; term =  -6.38660308379185e-09; approximation = -6.51335680512735e-11
> ```

## Error

As shown above, `approximation` converges on `1`, and *always* remains greater than the `limit` of `1e-10`.  So the condition is always `TRUE`, and the `while` loop continues indefinitely.

```r
#                                     |------ TRUE -------|
while(approximation < (limit*(-1)) || approximation > limit){
  # ...
}
```

But when `n` reaches `786`, your `term`'s numerator `((-1)^n)*((x)^(2*n))` maxes out at [`Inf`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/is.finite.html)inity.

```r
n <- 785
((-1)^n)*((x)^(2*n))
#> [1] -8.094815e+307

n <- 786
((-1)^n)*((x)^(2*n))
#> Inf
```

Now your denominator `factorial(2*n)` has been `Inf` for some time, ever since `n` reached `86`.

```r
n <- 85
factorial(2*n)
#> [1] 7.257416e+306

n <- 86
factorial(2*n)
#> [1] Inf
```

So until now, the overall quotient has been `0`: a finite number divided by `Inf`inity.  But when `n` reaches `786`, your `term` becomes `Inf / Inf`, which is [`NaN`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/is.finite.html): "Not a Number".

```r
n <- 785
c(((-1)^n)*((x)^(2*n)))/factorial(2*n)
#> [1] 0
-8.094815e+307 / Inf
#> [1] 0

n <- 786
c(((-1)^n)*((x)^(2*n)))/factorial(2*n)
#> [1] NaN
Inf / Inf
#> [1] NaN
```

When `approximation` is incremented by `NaN`, the result is still `NaN`.

```r
1 + NaN
#> [1] NaN
```

With an `approximation` of `NaN`, your `while` conditions evaluate to [`NA`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/NA.html): "Not Available".

```r
limit <- 1e-10

NaN < (limit*(-1))
#> [1] NA
NaN > limit
#> [1] NA

NA || NA
#> [1] NA
```

In your `while` loop, this `NA` condition throws the error you encountered.

```r
while(NA){
  # ...
}
#> Error in while (NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 4):

Compute the factorial and the powers of `x` using logarithms, then invert the logs.

In the question's code, if `n` starts at zero then `approximation` is off by `1`. The cosinus series expansion 1st term is `1` because `(-1)^0 == 1`.
So I start with `n <- 1` and `approximation <- 1`. This avoids having to treat the first case as a special case. I also change the stop criterion to one based on differences of two consecutive values. This allows for the computation of `cos(x)` to be more general and not depend on the input `x`. In  question's algorithm, only values with an approximate final value equal to zero were allowed.

As for the use of log factorials, the value of `(2n)!` grows rapidly and with a small enough allowed absolute error it would become `Inf`, and all next `term`'s would be zero, resulting in an infinite loop. `lfactorial` keeps the numbers amenable and the intermediate calculations finite.

Speed is not important so I keep the repeated calculation of `log(x)` in the loop, to have the formula used as close to the Taylor series expansion formula as possible. This calculation can (and should) be made before the loop. And multiplied by `2`, since we are at it.

```r
taylor_cos <- function(x, limit = 1e-10) {
  n <- 1
  approximation <- 1
  err <- Inf
  while(err > limit){
    lterm <- 2*n*log(x) - lfactorial(2*n)
    term <- (-1)^n * exp(lterm)
    previous <- approximation
    approximation <- previous + term
    err <- abs(previous - approximation)
    n <- n + 1L
  }
  approximation
}

taylor_cos(pi/2)
#> [1] 5.260102e-13
taylor_cos(pi/3)
#> [1] 0.5
taylor_cos(pi/6)
#> [1] 0.8660254
taylor_cos(pi/4)
#> [1] 0.7071068
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: this is nice, could you add some explanation to it to help me and other people understand why this is necessary?

Comment: I like the math trick to aid computation!  But the algorithm by OP (@user23327933) already yields that result for `n <- 1`, and where OP's code throws an error for `n <- 0`, **this logarithmic solution seems to loop infinitely**.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! This is really nice. There is a small typo I think, you can eliminate the line `limit <- 1e-10`, but you should set `limit = 1e-10` in the formals (instead of `1e10`).

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding The equal sign is to set a default, it's in the formals...

Answer (score 3):

Two points to address your issues:

1. Should initialize `n` with `1` instead of `0`,
2. Should be aware of precision loss in `factorial(2*n)` when `n` grows huge. (you can refer to [@Rui Barradas's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77916170/12158757), where `lfactorial` is used)

---

One workaround works like below

```
x <- pi / 2
n <- 1 # initialize by `1`
approximation <- 1
limit <- 1e-10
while (abs(approximation) > limit) {
  term <- (-1)^n * prod(x / seq_len(2 * n)) # refactor `x^(2*n)/factorial(2*n)` by `prod(x / seq_len(2 * n))` to keep the precision
  (n <- n + 1)
  (approximation <- approximation + term)
}
```

and you will obtain

```
> approximation
[1] -6.513356e-11
```